# What should happen next on init scripts?

Tags: linux, boot, linux-mint, init

I've been using a Linux Mint 13 live system on my memory stick and I decided to put it on my hard drive.

It already had several scripts to uninstall software and optimize it, scripts that I had to run on every single boot.

So I decided to take advantage of them to prepare an already optimized installation.

I installed syslinux on a small Fat 16 partition of the hard drive, put the syslinux.cfg, vmlinuz and initrd in there, and pointed the root partition as a ext2 partition that I made on that same hard drive.

I entered runlevel 1, unmounted everything that could be unmounted (everything but `/dev` and `/`) and copied everything to the that ext2 partition, copying /dev with a special option and everything else that should be done (I'm used to make custom live images like that, I boot it, make the modifications, enter runlevel 1, unmount file systems and copy everything from `/` to somewhere, so i can later repack it to a new squashfs file).

But now it's not working, and it gives me no clue about what's wrong. It just hangs after mounting the file systems and running the init scripts, no errors displayed. The disk has no accesses, everything stays still, and I can't use any terminal, the only thing I can do is reboot with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>

Here are the two screens:

The first is the main boot screen, and the other is the terminal 1, accessed by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (other terminals are empty)

[image]
[image]